# Running Julia code in Python for speed increase?

Tags: python, performance, julia

I have a module implemented in Numba (`njit` and `jitclass`) because its speed is critical. I might get non negligeable speed increase if I write it in Julia instead, but I would still need to run it in a larger Python project.

**Question:** In your opinion, is it worth rewriting the module in Julia?

 i.e. Will the speed gains Julia vs Numba be outweighted by the losses of running Julia modules in Python?

Thanks!

Comment: This is _very_ much a "benchmark for your workload" question -- and a huge amount of the answer may depend on the implementation details of the bulk of data in the result and how it's transferred across process boundaries. It's a _very_ different question if your logic is doing analysis providing a yes/no, vs taking a dataset of size N and merging analysis results into that with a N*4-sized result; the question is so high-level we can't distinguish between those cases at all right now.

Comment: In general yes. If tou have working numba code, do not expect Julia code to be orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Julia and Numba share the same back-end JIT compiler toolchain : LLVM. This means **most optimizations are the same** and the performance of low-level part of the code should be about the same.

That being said, the languages provide different **set of features** that introduces different **overheads**. On example is the modulus: `mod(-4, 10)` is `6` in both Julia and Python and can optimized the same way, but Julia provide a `%` operator that is faster for positive numbers and there is no equivalent in Python. While there are often ways to reduce such overhead, it is not always simple nor possible. An example for this is the bound checking: Julia uses bounds checking to ensure program safety *by default* (see [this](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/boundscheck/)) while Numba does not perform such a check *by default*, but it needs to check if the index is negative since Numpy supports that can result in a similar overhead. Assertions and loop analysis can help the compiler to generate a code without bound checks or negative index checks, but AFAIK there is no way to completely  remove this overhead in Numba when the indices are random/unknown. The garbage collection can also behave differently since Numba is based on scoped allocations and reference counting while Julia use a [generational mark&sweep garbage collector](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.9-dev/devdocs/gc/) (both have pros and cons).

The **implementation of the provided set of basic functions is different** so the performance can also be drastically different. For this part, the best is just to benchmark the implementation. If an implementation is slow, it can often be rewritten in the target language (assuming it worth the effort). For example, sorting array in Numba in a parallel code is not efficient due to the current implementation (creating expensive temporary arrays) but one can write a code not doing any allocations in the critical part of the code for the sake of performance. The set of basic data-structure and built-in functions available in Numba is pretty limited compared to Julia though. This can impact the **expressiveness** and thus the performance of the resulting code in the end.

Put it shortly, it is generally hard to compare the performance of languages, but both should be pretty **close in term of performance for low-level numerical codes working on relatively-large native arrays** (ie. with float/integers data types). IMHO, I do not think this is a good idea to rewrite a Python code to Julia just for the sake of performance.

If performance is so critical, then **please consider using a low-level native language like C/C++** that can be compiled statically. Such languages provide generally higher performance at the expense of a more limited set of features (at least, lower-level ones). Typically, the control of the memory in C is very low-level enabling optimizations that are not possible in Julia/Python, but it is also known to be bug prone. There is no GC or JIT overheads, nor any bound-checking in C (by default using mainstream compilers & practices). Not to mention native codes can benefit from architecture-specific instructions (eg. SIMD, popcount, advanced atomic instructions, etc.).

Comment: "Such languages provide generally higher performance" when comparing C/C++ to julia is generally false.

Comment: I don't think your modulus example is correct. `%` is remainder in Julia, while `mod` is the modulus. `mod` behaves the same as in Python, and I don't think there's a significant performance difference. It's not really about 'native vs user-friendly', they are two distinct operators.

Comment: @DNF Good point. I think my point was not clear. I wanted to point out that Python do not provide an equivalent to `a % b` in Julia and that the same operator syntax do not behave the same way. I edited the answer to clarify this point.

Comment: @OscarSmith Actually, the [**Julia Micro-Benchmarks website**](https://julialang.org/benchmarks/) itself shows the opposite of your claim. It is also confirmed by other [independent benchmarking websites](https://programming-language-benchmarks.vercel.app/julia-vs-cpp). It also matches with the detailed answer (more theoretical) explanation.

Comment: @OscarSmith An highly optimized C/C++ code hardly be slower than an highly optimized Julia code. It can be equally fast, but generally not much faster. The overhead of the GC and the JIT can be significant in many cases. In fields like high-performance computing (with complex data structures), game development, high-frequency trading and embedded software, a GC is never faster than a specialised allocator. The JIT provides no performance benefit compared to `-march=native -O3` (since it is not a tracing JIT) and Clang uses the same back-end anyway. I am open to facts proving the opposite.

Comment: For highly optimized code in both C++ and Julia, performance differences are likely to be small, at least for typical numerical codes. Jit overhead can be relevant, though. The question is, perhaps, which has the better performance per effort ratio.